# ViewScoped binding bug - fixed?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using Primefaces 3.5, and Mojarra 2.1.17 and I encountered today bug which is described [here](http://balusc.blogspot.co.at/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html#HeyTheresPitfallsInTheTitle). Though, I have read some answers on SO which says that the bug is currently fixed. Can someone tell me what I'm missing ?

Comment: `JavaFaces`? Did you mean `mojarra`?. Anyway I cannot load the `javaserverfaces.com` page that explains the error, but IIRC it was supposed to be fixed in mojarra-2.2 (which appears still not released, but it was due to be by march last time I checked). And once it gets released you would need to upgrade your `mojarra` versión in your server.

Comment: @SJuan76 Sorry for making you confused, actually I am using Mojarra, as you said. So is not released so far ?

Comment: Can't [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0-m11) be used?

Comment: Use Mojarra 2.1.x until Mojarra 2.2 released officially, till that you can use binding in view scope by setting javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to false for that particular page. As far as possible avoid using binding in viewscope

Comment: User @Jitesh is correct that you should avoid using binding in ViewScoped beans and JSTL should only be used for very specific things.  Turning partial-state-saving off may have unintended performance problems.

Comment: Thank you. @Jitesh can you put your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Mojarra 2.1.x until Mojarra 2.2 released officially, till that you can use binding in view scope by setting javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to false for that particular page. As far as possible avoid using binding in viewscope